# Monosnap on Windows - Shortcut key setting to copy to clipboard

Tags: image

In MacOS, I will modify my screenshot key to use monosnap and then after no modifications or minor ones, I will then use a shortcut key to place it in my clipboard.  I am trying to make the same workflow in the windows version.

Here is what I see:

[image]

I do not see a setting to "Copy image to clipboard":

[image]

If there another way to achieve my goal, please share.  Oh btw, I would rather not require the option to upload my images to an external service.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same:
 1. Focus your Monosnap Editor
 2. Press Ctrl+C

Now you have your edited image in clipboard.